# Why is vim's colorscheme not coloring the entire window?

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim

Only the portions of the terminal with text on it is colored. 
Not sure how to describe it, please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal supports 256 colours then set this in your .vimrc `se t_Co=256` If you're not sure or didn't work then set this in your .vimrc `se t_Co=16`.

Let me know if it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running vim inside terminal you have to change the colour palette of the gnome terminal to use theme colours. (Not required in a GUI version like gvim or macvim)

Comment: Yes, looks like the terminal background color is coming through.